# Reading an element from matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have the following matrix(`tic_tac_toe`) defined in R:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "O"  NA   "X"     
[2,] NA   "O"  "O" 
[3,] "X"  NA   "X"
```

When I try to access the element by using `tic_tac_toe[1,2]` and `tic_tac_toe[1][2]`, how these expressions are being read by R?

Comment: Hadley has a useful backgrounder in his book Advanced R:
http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html

Answer (score 0):

The first expression is read as follows :

```
`[`(tic_tac_toe,1,2)
```

i.e.: it applies the indexing function `[` with

- as first argument the matrix `tic_tac_toe`
- as second argument the selection in the first dimension (rows)
- as third argument the selection in the second dimension (columns)

The second expression is read as follows:

```
`[`( `[`(tic_tac_toe,1), 2)
```

So you first apply that indexing function to `tic_tac_toe` but this time with only one extra argument. This treats the matrix as a onedimensional object (a vector to be exact) and selects the first element. On this result you apply the indexing function again, but this time with 2 as the only argument. So you select the second element of the vector containing the first element of `tic_tac_toe`.

In short: your first expression makes sense, your second doesn't.

On a sidenote: a matrix is internally nothing else but a vector with a dimension attribute attached. That is why a matrix is treated as a vector if you only use indices for one dimension.